# BigQuery : filter repeated fields with standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table :

```
row | query_params | query_values
1     foo            bar  
      param          val
2     foo            baz
```

JSON :

```
{ 
"query_params" : [ "foo", "param"], 
"query_values" : [ "bar", "val" ] 
}, { 
"query_params" : [ "foo" ], 
"query_values" : [ "baz" ] 
}
```

Using standard SQL I want to filter repeated field on their value, something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE query_params = 'foo'
```

Which would output

```
row | query_params | query_values
1     foo            bar  
2     foo            baz
```

PS : for the same question using legacy SQL, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098239/bigquery-filter-repeated-fields-with-legacy-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen the topic in the migration guide on [differences in filtering repeated fields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#filtering_repeated_fields)? Using your sample data as a basis, and assuming that the params and values repeat together (as opposed to being separate arrays), you can write a query such as:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS row, ARRAY<STRUCT<param STRING, value STRING>>[
      ('foo', 'bar'), ('param', 'val')] AS queries UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ARRAY<STRUCT<param STRING, value STRING>>[('foo', 'baz')]
)
SELECT * EXCEPT (queries)
FROM T, UNNEST(queries)
WHERE param = 'foo';
```

The important part here is the `,` between `T` and the `UNNEST(queries)`, which takes the cross product of the rows of `T` and the elements in `queries`. This is equivalent to using `JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN` in place of the comma as well.

The query also uses `EXCEPT (queries)` to avoid selecting the original array in the query result, since we only want the "flattened" contents of the array.

Edit: Another sample query, this time where the params and values repeat independently:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS row, ['foo', 'param'] AS query_params,
    ['bar', 'val'] AS query_values UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['foo'], ['baz']
)
SELECT row, query_param, query_values[OFFSET(o)] AS query_value
FROM T, UNNEST(query_params) AS query_param WITH OFFSET o
WHERE query_param = 'foo';
```

This uses the offset within `query_params` to index into `query_values` in parallel.

Comment: Your schema is "queries": [
      {
        "param": "foo",
        "value": "bar"
      },
      {
        "param": "param",
        "value": "val"
      }
    ], 
Mine is "query_params" : [ "foo", "param"], "query_values" : [ "bar", "val" ]

I did not see the doc you pointed to because I am not migrating from legacy but starting fresh with standar, I will take a look.

Comment: I added another sample query where the two columns repeat independently. I don't know that we have any examples like this in the existing documentation but it may be useful to add one (I'll follow up with our doc writer). Thanks!

Comment: Wow I didn't know you could use offset like this, brilliant! that should be added to the OFFSET doc. And I also think the documentation in "migrating from legacy to standard SQL" should be renamed to something else or reworked because it contains useful information for people who are not migrating.

Comment: Ok so now I need to do exactly the same thing using legacy SQL, this is a nightmare ahah, created another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098239/bigquery-filter-repeated-fields-with-legacy-sql