# BigQuery : filter repeated fields with legacy SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table :

```
row | query_params | query_values
1     foo            bar  
      param          val
2     foo            baz
```

JSON :

```
{ 
"query_params" : [ "foo", "param"], 
"query_values" : [ "bar", "val" ] 
}, { 
"query_params" : [ "foo" ], 
"query_values" : [ "baz" ] 
}
```

Using legacy SQL I want to filter repeated field on their value, something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE query_params = 'foo'
```

Which would output

```
row | query_params | query_values
1     foo            bar  
2     foo            baz
```

PS : this question is related to the same question but using standard SQL answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000674/bigquery-filter-repeated-fields-with-standard-sql)

Comment: I'll try to answer your question unless someone beats me to it, but can you explain why you need to use legacy SQL? We want to make sure that we are aware of any incompatibilities with standard SQL so that we can address them. Thanks!

Comment: I am migrating a custom dashboard to Mode Analytics, but I just found out that Mode does not support standard SQL yet.

Comment: Just to confirm, I'm guessing that the [`#standardSQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#sql-prefix) trick doesn't work there either, right?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any better ideas for legacy SQL aside from using a `JOIN` after flattening each array separately. If you have a table `T` with the contents indicated above, you can do:

```
SELECT
  [t1.row],
  t1.query_params,
  t2.query_values
FROM
  FLATTEN((SELECT [row], query_params, POSITION(query_params) AS pos
           FROM T WHERE query_params = 'foo'), query_params) AS t1
JOIN
  FLATTEN((SELECT [row], query_values, POSITION(query_values) AS pos
           FROM T), query_values) AS t2
ON [t1.row] = [t2.row] AND
  t1.pos = t2.pos;
```

The idea is to associate the elements of the two arrays by row and position after filtering for `query_params` that are equal to `'foo'`.

Comment: Problem is [row] is not a column. I tried using ROW_NUMBER() OVER() [row] instead, but I get "Using repeated fields with analytic functions is disallowed"

Comment: It looks like Mode Analytics supports [setting standard SQL for your BigQuery connection](https://help.modeanalytics.com/articles/using-standard-or-legacy-sql/) now, so you should probably just use that :) You can also use `#standardSQL` in the query text itself.

Comment: Yes, but I switched to Metabase after Mode increased their price plan and they do not support standard SQL yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try below version

```
    SELECT [row], query_params, query_values 
    FROM (
        SELECT [row], query_params, param_pos, query_values, POSITION(query_values) AS value_pos 
        FROM FLATTEN((
            SELECT [row], query_params, POSITION(query_params) AS param_pos, query_values 
            FROM YourTable
        ), query_params)
        WHERE query_params = 'foo'
    )
    WHERE param_pos = value_pos
```