# BigQuery : filter repeated fields together with normal field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table :

```
row | cust_id | name
1   | 34      | word1 word2 someworkd  
    |         | something word1
    |         | blabla
2   | 35      | word1 word2 word3
    |         | word4 word5
```

select * result JSON

```
[
  {
    "cust_id": "34",
    "name": [
      "word1 word2 someworkd",
      "something word1",
      "blabla"
    ]
  },
  {
    "cust_id": "35",
    "name": [
      "word1 word2 word3",
      "word4 word5",
      "word1word5"
    ]
  }
]
```

schema JSON:

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "cust_id",
    "type": "STRING"

  },
  {
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "name",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

I want to filter by cust_id and  repeated field on their value so with query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE  cust_id='34' and name like'%word1%'
```

Expected output from query:

```
row | cust_id | name
1   | 34      | word1 word2 someworkd  
    |         | something word1
```

Expected output from query in JSON format:

```
  {
    "cust_id": "34",
    "name": [
      "word1 word2 someworkd",
      "something word1"
    ]
  }
]
```

Inspired by this question [BigQuery : filter repeated fields with standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000674/bigquery-filter-repeated-fields-with-standard-sql)
I try this query :

```
SELECT cust_id, name   FROM `mytable`, UNNEST(name) AS name WITH OFFSET o
WHERE name like '%word1%' and cust_id='34'
```

Which outputs this:

```
row | cust_id | name
1   | 34      | word1 word2 someworkd  
    | 34      | something word1
```

Output JSON:

```
[
  {
    "cust_id": "34",
    "name": "word1 word2 someworkd"
  },
  {
    "cust_id": "34",
    "name": "something word1"
  }
]
```

Output result is not the same that I would like to have, how can I achieve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

I will post solution I did which works as I need, maybe useful for others

```
SELECT
  cust_id,
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    name
  FROM
    `mytable`,
    UNNEST(name) AS name
  WHERE
    name LIKE '%word1%'
    AND cust_id='34') AS name
FROM
  `mytable`
WHERE
  cust_id="34"
```

Result:

```
row | cust_id | name
1   | 34      | word1 word2 someworkd  
    |         | something word1
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "cust_id": "34",
    "name": [
      "word1 word2 someworkd",
      "something word1"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
    ARRAY(SELECT * FROM t.name WHERE name LIKE'%word1%') 
  AS name)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE cust_id = 34
```