# How to filter nested column in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, nested

I have a bigquery table which looks like below:

[image]

The column details says it's of type "*REPEATED*". So I guess that's the word for nested column, and it indeed looks like one. I would like to filter on this particular `NAME` column like below:

```
WITH T AS (
SELECT 
CUST_ID,NAME
FROM Table
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(NAME)
FROM T, UNNEST(NAME)
WHERE NAME LIKE '%VERMA%'
```

I tried above snippet from the solution to a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000674/bigquery-filter-repeated-fields-with-standard-sql). But it is throwing me an error:

[image]

I tried different things like using `IN` etc but failing. Does anyone know the correct syntax to use here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you are just missing the alias for your unnest field:

See if following works:

```
WITH T AS (
SELECT 
123 as CUST_ID, ["JOHN", "DOE"]  as NAME
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(NAME)
FROM T, UNNEST(NAME) as name_value
WHERE name_value LIKE '%JOHN%'
```